# Querying Mysql with Python. Regex in query not working

Tags: python, mysql, regex, python-3.x

I am attempting to query a mysql database from within a python script. My normal queries are working but I'm having an issue when matching on a regex in the mysql query, specifically when using things like "\d" to try and match a number.

This is what my query looks like:

```
mycursor.execute("SELECT name1, name2 FROM databasename where name1 REGEXP '^test\d\..*' ")
```

The contents of these fields in the database are like this:

```
test0.something
test1.somethingelse
testing0.something
```

so in this example I'd like to match the first 2 rows but I am getting nothing.

I've tried adjusting the query to be

```
mycursor.execute("SELECT name1, name2 FROM databasename where name1 REGEXP '^test.*' ")
```

and that query actually works but returns all 3 rows.

I've also tried

```
mycursor.execute("SELECT name1, name2 FROM databasename where name1 REGEXP '^test0.*' ")
```

but then obviously I miss the second row.

It appears that the \d is causing the problem... how would I go about using \d in a query like this inside python code?

Comment: Use `'^test[0-9]\.'`

Comment: Thanks Wiktor... I did try searching but couldn't find an example like mine, clearly didn't search hard enough :) your suggestions works. Is it just impossible to use \d then?

Comment: POSIX regex does not support Perl-like shorthand character classes. Some POSIX regex implementations support those, but not MySQL versions before 8.x (where ICU regex engine is used).

Comment: Thanks!! wish I could upvote these comments :)